# nginx localhost config file doesn't work

Tags: php, nginx

I am using WPM-XM stack on Windows. I am working of two php projects pcm, pcx in a localhost environment.

I want pcm project to use pcm.conf file. But I'm not abele to do so. Here's the pcm.conf file's content:

```
server {
        # access from localhost only
        listen       127.0.0.1:80;
        server_name  localhost/pcm;

        # the following default "catch-all" configuration, allows access to the server from outside.
        # please ensure your firewall allows access to tcp/port 80. check your "skype" config.
        # listen       80;
        # server_name  _;

        log_not_found off;
        charset utf-8;

        access_log  logs/pcm.log  main;
        error_log logs/pcme.log;


        # handle files in the root path /www
        location / {
            root         /www/pcm;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   www;
        }

        location /pcxxc/ {
        deny all;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files      $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass   php;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            #fastcgi_param  PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 1000;
            #fastcgi_param  PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN 100;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_real_ip;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # add expire headers and speed up image access with a vary header
        location ~* ^.+.(gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|flv|swf|pdf|mp3|mp4|xml|txt|js|css)$ {
            expires 30d;
            add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
        }

        # only allow these request methods
        if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ){ return 405; }

        # deny access to .htaccess files (if Apache's document root concurs with nginx's one)
        # deny access to git & svn repositories
        location ~ /(\.ht|\.git|\.svn) {
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
            deny  all;
        }
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to access the url localhost/pcm/pcxxc/ to check whether the config file is working or not. Instead of displaying access denied/you don't have permission to access the file error. Nginx reports 404 not found error.

The folder where the above config file is saved has been added in main nginx config file

How to setup configuration files for multiple projects in Nginx (Windows) correctly?

Comment: edit your hostfile in `%windir%\sys32\etc\drivers` then add `127.0.0.1  pcm.local` and then edit your nginx config as this : `server_name  pcm.local;` restart nginx server, goto url `http://pcm.local/` enjoy ;)

Comment: I have tried this before I published the question. pcm.local opens the configuration panel of wpn-xm.

Comment: then you have to check the wpn-xm config, there is something catching all but localhost, I don't remember where ...

Comment: the problem was the path /www/pcm/. Nginx was not able to locate the root. It was serving webinterface php index.php instead of my project's index.php

Answer (score 0):

The `/pcm/pcxxc/` request is matched by your `location /` which tries to serve some index file under directory `/www/pcm/pcm/pcxxc/` and failed.